# Archive template

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

I have several custom post types and we need to create separate archive templates for these. I tried the following advice, but it's still using the default archive template.

> In the form of the single-type-template. In the same way that posts
>   are shown on their own page with single.php, custom post types will
>   use single-{posttype}.php if it's available.
>
> So for the above example, you could create a single-acme_product.php
>   file and the product posts would be shown using that template.
>
> In the form of the archive-type-template. In the same way that posts
>   are shown on their own archive with archive.php, custom post types
>   will use archive-{posttype}.php if it's available.
>
> So for the above example, you could create a archive-acme_product.php
>   file and the product posts would be shown using that template.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is my code**

```
function camps_register_post_type() {
   register_post_type('camps', array(
       'labels' => array(
           'name' => 'Camps & holidays',
           'singular_name' => 'Camps & holidays',
           'add_new' => 'Add New Camps & holidays',
           'edit_item' => 'Edit Camps & holidays',
           'new_item' => 'New Camps & holidays',
           'view_item' => 'View Camps & holidays',
           'search_items' => 'Search Camps & holidays',
           'not_found' => 'No Camps & holidays found',
           'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Camps & holidays found in Trash'
       ),
       'public' => true,
       'has_archive' => true,
       'rewrite' => array("slug" => "camps"), // the slug for permalinks
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
   ));
}
```

Comment: That advice looks correct. Now please post your code.

Comment: Specifically, we need to see your `register_post_type()` call.

Comment: And what, *exactly*, have you named your template files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom post type with slug `camps`:

- Single post template: `single-camps.php`
- Archive index template: `archive-camps.php`

Comment: This is what we have named it: single-camps.php (which seems to work) but archive-camps.php doesn't

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you sure the problem is the *template file*, or might it be the *rewrite rules*?

Comment: Just so I am sure, should the URl to view the archive-camps.php be www.domain.com/camps?

Comment: Yes: if your CPT slug is `camps`, the default URI will be `example.com/camps`.

Comment: My apologies, I was looking at the wrong page, duh. That is all working fine now. Thank you so much for your help.